# What is it for the pedantic flag in LOCAL_CFLAGS

Tags: android-ndk

What is the of the "-pedantic" flag in LOCAL_CFLAGS for Android.mk builds?
And is there any place to find all the possible flags and their meaning?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the Android build systems, but `CFLAGS` is usually a variable describing flags to pass to the C compiler.

If you use the *clang* or *GCC* compiler families, the `-pedantic` flag enables particularly "picky" warnings about your code. See the [option index](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Index.html) and the [warnings section](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warnings-and-Errors.html#index-pedantic-3922) for GCC.